# Laravel 5 - Inserting all POST data into database?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 5 and I created a resource controller, setup routing and setup my database model.

My question is: when I do a **POST**, my store method is called on the controller but how can I take the request data and insert a new entry in the db without having to explicitly set every field?

Here's my code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $data = $request->all(); // this grabs all my request data - great!
  $user = new User;
  $user-> ??? // insert ALL posted data
  $user->save();
}
```

I understand that I can do...

```
$user->name = $request->name;
```

...for every field. But can someone tell me how to insert everything?

I realize I can probably do a foreach but I'm wondering if there's something better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is method `fill` in every model https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_fill:

```php
$user->fill($request->all());
```

Eventually you can use `create`:

```php
\User::create($request->all());
```

This above is called mass asignment and there is section about this in Eloquents documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent
You need to define which keys might be set:

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    // The attributes that are mass assignable
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'login', 'birthdate'];
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks @ofca